# Why does adding a new code file to a C# program cause a form (menu) to be created?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a Java programmer new to C#.  I've created a C# WinForms program.  It is intended to have a single form.  All well and good.

That is, until I create a new Code File, and add it to the project.  Then in Solution Explorer, whenever I select the new code file, it brings up a blank form.  I had no intention of creating a new form - just a new code file.  Can I eliminate this new form?  It creates a new form for every code file I add, and that was not my intention.  I merely want to add code files without Visual Studio creating a new form every time I do.

Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you select your project -> right click -> new element - You need to choose "C# Class" not "C# Windows Form".

If you right click the form in the inspector you can delete the form or view it's code.

Edit:

On the right panel where you have your solution - do not select the solution but the element below it. When you have it selected, right click and choose 'Add -> New Element'. Then from the list choose "Class". Then you double click the class in the right side panel and that should bring your code file up not the form.

Edit2:

```
using System;

namespace CDP
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public PassFail PassFailVerify()
        {
            return PassFail.Pass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I chose "Code File", not "C# Windows Forms", when I created these new files.  I even tried creating a file in TextPad, adding code to it, and simply adding that file to the project.  And when I select it in Solution Explorer, it brings up a blank form that I had no intention of creating.

Comment: On the right panel where you have your solution - do not select the solution but the element below it. When you have it selected, right click and choose 'Add -> New Element'. Then from the list choose "Class".

Then you double click the class in the right side panel and that should bring your code file up not the form.

Comment: Well, I thought it worked.  They showed up as C# icons for a minute, but when I added my code, they changed icons and began bringing up blank forms when selected.  The code I added was the following.  

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CDP {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private PassFail Verify() {
            return PassFail.Pass;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of how it looks like?

Comment: What your adding here is essentially a code to create a new windows form

Comment: @RickyBobby See the Edit2 in my answer, paste that code.